# login control authentication not working with user defined database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I setup a login control to use on my web application and having issues. I am trying to authenticate login control with a user defined sql database but its showing an error of **inavalid column name 'password'**. I have tried almost everything but it is not working. I have no idea where am i mistaking. If someone can please help me out. Here is my code.

```
protected void login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter myadp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    myadp.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand();
    myadp.SelectCommand.Connection = mycon;
    mycon.Open();
    myadp.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select *from UserData where username=@uname and password=@pswd";
    myadp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",login1.UserName);
    myadp.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pswd",login1.Password);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    dr = myadp.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read())
    {
        e.Authenticated = true;
        Session["username"] = login1.UserName;
        Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<Script>alert('Error')</Script>");
    }  
    mycon.Close();
}
```

Comment: **inavalid column name 'password'** This is your problem. You don't have this column in your database.

Comment: make sure your **password** is exist in your database. or make sure it is spell correctly, perhaps you stored **pwd** (just an example)in your database?

Comment: never mind. Solved it. Yeah just saw it.

Comment: But mmy login status is not working with it. Can you help me with that

Comment: What do you mean your login status not working?

Comment: Just for your information. you don't have to store your username in session as you can always get the logged in username by **User.Identity.Name** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx

Comment: It means when i log in. login status does not change to logout

Answer (score 0):

For your first question as the comments says you don't have `password` field in your database
for second question :- you are checking `if(dr.Read)` you should check `if(dr.HasRows)`. you don't have need to store username in session. you can get it by `User.Identity.Name` as @chinz says. Also in your web.config

```
<system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
                   <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name="login" protection="All"/>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
       </authorization>
</system.web>
```

this will increase the security of your page. For Proper Authentication method see [msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1250726.aspx?How%20to%20Authenticate%20Users%20with%20the%20SQL%20Server%20database%20table%20using%20C%20with%20Example%20)